# solr search results return a multivalued field as a single string in highlighting

Tags: solr

I have a multivalued field that I am searching on. In the 'result' area the field is returned as an array of strings. In the highlighting section the array elements are combined into a single string with no delimiter. Do I have to parse the highlighting based on the results section? It seems like highlighting should return an array of strings.

This is what I get back:

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
        <arr name="NameList">
            <str>Beacher, Mike</str>
            <str>Cally, Karl T.</str>
            <str>Amerson, Judy</str>
        </arr>
    </doc>
</result>
<lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="my_doc">
        <arr name="NameList">
            <str>Beacher, MikeCally, Karl T.<em>Amerson, Judy</em>
            </str>
        </arr>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

I was expecting the highlighting result to look something like this:

```
<arr name="NameList">
    <str>Beacher, Mike</str>
    <str>Cally, Karl T.</str>
    <str><em>Amerson, Judy</em></str>
</arr>
```

So far I haven't found any questions about this - unless I am just bad at searching. :)

Answer (score 3):

Solved it.

This functionality is now available using the `preserveMulti` parameter in Solr 4.1.

Discussed **[here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-dev/201209.mbox/%3C1491213873.130736.1348695188723.JavaMail.jiratomcat@arcas%3E)**

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work for me. When I enable it, I still get one value returned. I really need a list to be returned. The documentation says that `preserveMulti` just maintains the order. It doesn't mention anything about whether the result is a list or a string.

Comment: Unable to remember the specifics since I posted this answer quite a while back (a month short of 3 years in fact). Solr is now at 5.5.0 - if you look into the latest docs, I believe you'll be able to find a way to get the required functionality.

Comment: Would if I could. Updating is a big project that we haven't **yet** had a need for. Yet.

Comment: Looks like this [only works with the standard highlighter](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3897), not the FastVectorHighlighter: "The "preserveMulti" parameter works with the default standard highlighter and follows the standard highlighting conventions."

Comment: please use f.cat.hl.preserveMulti=true in order to highlight specific multivalued field.